# How to pass a parameter to a component's templateUrl in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

Here is the situation. I have an Angular component whose HTML template includes a reference to another component.

The part in the parent component's template looks like this:

```
        <div id="childComponent">
          <!-- Child component should appear here -->
            <child-component></child-component>
        </div>
```

and the child component's definition looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    templateUrl: "ChildComponentController/ChildComponent",
})
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

The idea is that the child component actually gets its HTML template from an ASP.NET controller. The problem is that "ChildComponentController/ChildComponent" is not enough, the controller method has a mandatory input parameter, let's call it ID. So what I am after is something like this:

```
        <div id="childComponent">
          <!-- Child component should appear here -->
            <child-component [ID]="this.idValue"></child-component>
        </div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    templateUrl: "ChildComponentController/ChildComponent?ID=" + this.ID,
})
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

But I don't know if it's possible to pass parameters to a component's templateUrl like this. Can this somehow be done?

Comment: This won't compile and I am a little confused by this. Are you trying to load a template at runtime using the templateUrl in the Component decorator?

Comment: I know it won't compile. I am after a solution that will compile.
Yes, I am trying to load a template at runtime. The ASP.NET controller will return the source code of an HTML document depending on what value it was given in the ID parameter. The Angular component will then use this as a template.
Note that the HTML document returned by the controller does not have any bindings to the Angular component's data. The values in the document will be already handled by the controller depending on what value the ID parameter has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the template returned by the controller doesn't have any Angular bindings then this is pretty straight forward. Basically you need to make a few changes to the ChildComponent and make an http request to get the template as a string and insert it into the DOM. Inserting html like this only works if there are no Angular bindings in it because there is not compiler at runtime to compile the bindings. Also note that 'templateUrl' has been change to 'template' for an inline template.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    template: '<div [innerHtml]="template"></div>
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() id: string;

  template: SafeHtml;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient
      .get(`ChildComponentController/ChildComponent?ID=${this.ID}`, { responseType: "text" 
      }).pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.template = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
      });
  }
}
```

It is important that the request responseType is set to text. If it is omitted then the HttpClient assumes the response is JSON and will try to parse it. Also, depending on your requirements you probably want to create a TemplateService that gets the templates and caches them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I didn't get the "take(1)" part to work, but it turned out I don't even need it. The Angular code happily called the ASP.NET controller, which rendered the document all OK and gave it back to Angular, which displayed it in the <div> element.
Caching the templates is pretty much useless because I only need to do this once per user session and the ID parameter gets a different value in every session.